# QVideoFrame::map() crashes

Tags: android, c++, qt, opengl-es, android-ndk

I am trying to get images from the camera using QCamera.
I thought I should derive from `QAbstractVideoSurface` and implement `present()`, where a `QVideoFrame`, representing the current image captured by the camera, is sent as a parameter.

As I need to do some processing, I tried to `map()` my frame, get the data with `bits()`, do whatever I have to do, then `unmap()` it. However I have a crash on `map()`

Here are the errors I get :

```
W libTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): Unsupported viewfinder pixel format
D SensorManager: registerListener :: 6, LSM6DSL Acceleration Sensor, 200000, 0,
E libEGL  : call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
E GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-0-546-0] attachToContext: invalid current EGLDisplay
F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x4 in tid 663 (qtMainLoopThrea)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Here is a full application code :

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////
//main.cpp
///////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "camera_engine.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    CameraEngine camEngine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("cameraEngine", &camEngine);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////
//camera_engine.h
///////////////////////////////////////////////

#ifndef __CAMERA_ENGINE_H__
#define __CAMERA_ENGINE_H__

#include <QCamera>

#include "image_reader.h"

class CameraEngine : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CameraEngine(QCamera::Position pos = QCamera::BackFace);
    ~CameraEngine();

public slots:
    void start();
private:
    QCamera mCamera;
    ImageReader mImageReader;
};

#endif  // __CAMERA_ENGINE_H__


///////////////////////////////////////////////
//camera_engine.cpp
///////////////////////////////////////////////

#include "camera_engine.h"

CameraEngine::CameraEngine(QCamera::Position pos) : mCamera(pos)
{
    mCamera.setViewfinder(&mImageReader);

    QCameraViewfinderSettings viewFinderSettings;
    viewFinderSettings.setResolution(640, 480);
    viewFinderSettings.setMinimumFrameRate(30);
    viewFinderSettings.setMaximumFrameRate(30);
    viewFinderSettings.setPixelFormat(QVideoFrame::Format_RGB24);
    mCamera.setViewfinderSettings(viewFinderSettings);
}

CameraEngine::~CameraEngine()
{
    if (mCamera.state() == QCamera::ActiveState) {
        mCamera.stop();
    }
}

void CameraEngine::start()
{
    mCamera.start();
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////
//image_reader.h
///////////////////////////////////////////////

#ifndef CAMERA_IMAGE_READER_H
#define CAMERA_IMAGE_READER_H

#include <QAbstractVideoSurface>

class ImageReader : public QAbstractVideoSurface {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ImageReader() = default;
    ~ImageReader() = default;

    virtual bool present(const  QVideoFrame& frame);
    virtual QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat> supportedPixelFormats(QAbstractVideoBuffer::HandleType type) const;
};

#endif  // CAMERA_IMAGE_READER_H


///////////////////////////////////////////////
//image_reader.cpp
///////////////////////////////////////////////

#include "image_reader.h"
#include <QDebug>

bool ImageReader::present(const QVideoFrame &frame)
{
    QVideoFrame currentFrame = frame;

    currentFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly); //crashes here
    // Do something
    currentFrame.unmap();

    return true;
}

QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat> ImageReader::supportedPixelFormats(QAbstractVideoBuffer::HandleType type) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(type)
    return QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat>() << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB24;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////
//main.qml
///////////////////////////////////////////////

import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window

    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Component.onCompleted: cameraEngine.start()
}
```

Edit: So, I think this might be because my QVideoFrame is stored as an OpenGL texture, and my `present()` function might not be running on the OpenGL thread, thus not finding the OpenGL ES Context.
Is there a way to make sure it's running on the right thread ?

Edit2: I found this : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html

Maybe I can adapt this code to get a valid OpenGL ES context. Unfortunately I have no time to do it now. I'll try that Monday, unless someone have a better suggestion, and tell you the results.

Edit3: So, apparently my solution was not the good one, I get a crash (SIGSEGV) on `initializeOpenGLFunctions();`

I saw Antonio Dias' answer, using a `VideoOutput` with the function `grabToImage`, tried it, and it seemed to work, but, if I understand correctly, `grabToImage` "draws" the `VideoOutput` in CPU memory, and I lose some metadata I was planning to get with `QMediaMetaData` in the process.

I also tried to use the NDK directly, but the camera requires an API level of at least 24, and even after setting all relevant settings I found, it does not seem to use it.

Edit4: I actually do not know what I did, but my program ended up using the right API level, so I'll go with the NDK solution for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work. Apparently `QCamera` has some problems on Android, so I had to use a QML `Camera`, and display it with a `VideoOutput`, and apply a filter through which I can get my images.

This filter is made in two parts : one deriving from [`QAbstractVideoFilter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractvideofilter.html), the other deriving from [`QVideoFilterRunnable`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideofilterrunnable.html).

Here is the code :

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// main.cpp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include "myfilter.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    qmlRegisterType<MyFilter>("example.myfilter", 1, 0, "MyFilter");

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// myfilter.hpp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#ifndef MYFILTER_H
#define MYFILTER_H

#include <QAbstractVideoFilter>

class MyFilterRunnable : public QVideoFilterRunnable {
public:
    QVideoFrame run(QVideoFrame *input, const QVideoSurfaceFormat &surfaceFormat, RunFlags flags);
};


class MyFilter : public QAbstractVideoFilter
{
public:
    QVideoFilterRunnable* createFilterRunnable();
};

#endif // MYFILTER_H

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// myfilter.cpp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include "myfilter.hpp"

#include <QOpenGLContext>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>

QVideoFrame MyFilterRunnable::run(QVideoFrame *input, const QVideoSurfaceFormat &surfaceFormat, QVideoFilterRunnable::RunFlags flags)
{
    QImage img(input->width(), input->height(), QImage::Format_RGBA8888);
    bool success = false;
    if (input->handleType() == QAbstractVideoBuffer::GLTextureHandle) {
        GLuint textureId = input->handle().toUInt();
        QOpenGLContext *ctx = QOpenGLContext::currentContext();
        QOpenGLFunctions *f = ctx->functions();
        GLuint fbo;
        f->glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
        GLuint prevFbo;
        f->glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, (GLint *) &prevFbo);
        f->glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
        f->glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId, 0);
        f->glReadPixels(0, 0, input->width(), input->height(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.bits());
        f->glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, prevFbo);
        success = true;
    } // else handle other types

    if( success ) {
        // Process image
        return QVideoFrame(img);
    } else {
        return *input; //Could not apply filter, return unmodified input
    }
}

QVideoFilterRunnable *MyFilter::createFilterRunnable()
{
    return new MyFilterRunnable;
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// main.qml
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtMultimedia 5.9
import example.myfilter 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window

    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Camera {
        id: camera
    }
    MyFilter {
        id: filter
    }
    VideoOutput {
        source: camera
        autoOrientation: true
        filters: [ filter ]
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

(My `run` implementation is adapted from here : http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtmultimedia.git/tree/examples/multimedia/video/qmlvideofilter_opencl/rgbframehelper.h)

Answer (score 0):

> **...unless someone have a better suggestion...**

My simple way to capture images from `Camera` object in QML is calling `grabToImage` and pass the image to C++ to process it!

This method does not oblige you to process all the frames of the active camera, you can grab only when you are ready or desire it!

Keep in mind, especially in android, that the `VideoOutput` object needs to be visible in order to grab anything, you can't, for example, grab images with screen turned off on Android. However you not need to fill the screen, you only have to gave some area of the screen to the `VideoOutput` and keep it visible and on top.

Also, note that reduce the size of `VideoOutput` does not reduce the maximum size you can capture, for example you can capture a 1280x720 image with a `VideoOutput` with smaller size.

Also the aspect ratio must be preserved when resizing `VideoOutput` to keep the aspect ratio of the image.

Code:

You can see full source [here](https://github.com/antonypro/CameraCaptureQMLDemo)!

main.cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "camerahelper.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    CameraHelper camera_helper;
    camera_helper.start(engine.rootObjects().first());

    return app.exec();
}
```

camerahelper.h:

```
#ifndef CAMERAHELPER_H
#define CAMERAHELPER_H

#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtQuick>

class CameraHelper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CameraHelper(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:

public slots:
    void start(QObject *qml_obj);
    void grab();

private slots:
    void frameReady(const QVariant &frame_variant);

private:
    QObject *m_qml_obj;
};

#endif // CAMERAHELPER_H
```

camerahelper.cpp:

```
#include "camerahelper.h"

CameraHelper::CameraHelper(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void CameraHelper::start(QObject *qml_obj)
{
    m_qml_obj = qml_obj;

    //Connect the QML frameReady SIGNAL to our frameReady SLOT
    connect(m_qml_obj, SIGNAL(frameReady(QVariant)), this, SLOT(frameReady(QVariant)));

    //Do the first grab
    grab();
}

void CameraHelper::grab()
{
    //Size of the captured image
    QSize size = QSize(320, 240);

    //Pass grab size to QML and wait for captured image on the frameReady SIGNAL
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_qml_obj, "grab", Q_ARG(QVariant, size.width()), Q_ARG(QVariant, size.height()));
}

void CameraHelper::frameReady(const QVariant &frame_variant)
{
    QQuickItemGrabResult *grab_result = qvariant_cast<QQuickItemGrabResult*>(frame_variant); //Cast from QVariant
    QImage frame = grab_result->image(); //Get the QImage
    grab_result->deleteLater(); //Release QQuickItemGrabResult

    //Depending on OS the image can have different formats,
    //use convertToFormat to unify all possibles formats to one
    frame = frame.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB32);

    //Frame is ready to use

    grab(); //Do the next frame grab
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.10
import QtMultimedia 5.8

Window
{
    visible: true
    color: "black"
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    signal frameReady(var frame)

    Camera
    {
        id: camera
        viewfinder.resolution: "320x240"
    }

    VideoOutput
    {
        id: videoOutput
        source: camera
        autoOrientation: true
        visible: true
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    function grab(grab_width, grab_height)
    {
        if (!visible)
            return

        videoOutput.grabToImage(function(frame)
        {
            frameReady(frame) //Emit frameReady SIGNAL
        }, Qt.size(grab_width, grab_height))
    }
}
```